# A Problem about the Solution of a SDE in an ODE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

The following came up as an additional question in a financial mathematics course:

[image]

I am guessing that I should attack this problem with Ito's lemma, which applying to $S(X_t)$ I think gives:

$$
dS(X_t)=\frac{1}{2}\sigma(X_t)^2 S''(X_t)dt + S'(X_t)\sigma(X_t)dW_t
$$

This seemed to me to be promising, given that we have the $\frac{1}{2}(\sigma(x))^2S''(x)$ term 'recovered' but I'm not really sure where to go from here, or how the $b(X_t)$ term is going to come into play?

For context, the course this was in doesn't go into very much detail about SDEs, just mentions Ito's lemma and the Feynman-Kac theorem, and solves a few simple SDEs.

Comment: I think you forgot the $b(X_t)dt$ in $dX_t$, which will give you the $b(X_t)S'(X_t)dt$ term when you apply Ito's formula

Comment: Yes @user6247850 I think you're right - Ito's lemma should give: $dS(X_t)=\frac{1}{2}\sigma(X_t)^2 S''(X_t)dt + S'(X_t)\color{red}{dX_t}$ so using the SDE we have $\frac{1}{2}\sigma(X_t)^2 S''(X_t)dt + S'(X_t)\sigma(X_t)dW_t + S'(X_t)b(X_t)dt $, so the first and last terms cancel to give, $dY_t = \sigma(X_t)S'(X_t)dW_t$, but then I'm not sure where we go from here?

Comment: @JacobM That’s the punchline right there at the end of your last comment: $Y_t$ consequently has no drift, so it’s a (local) martingale.

Comment: Oh I see @NapD.Lover that makes sense! Thanks